# How to use two database in propel

Tags: php, propel

I have been integrating propel application,I just wanted to use two databases. But I don't know how to define in schema and build.properties files.can any one let me know what should I do to have multiple database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write two schema with different database names and configure a runtime-conf.xml file.
See: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html