# Propel Multiple Database Modeling

Tags: php, database-design, model, propel

I've just started working with Propel and I love it, but I have a question regarding how to utilize multiple database connections.  I know I can set stuff up in my schema to connect to multiple different databases, but I'm curious how to handle this in code.

The issue I have is multiple databases, and each of them has slightly different schemas with no data warehousing.  As a result I have things resembling the following:

```
databaseName: westCoastUsers
table: users
column1: email
column2: password
column3: FirstName

databaseName: eastCoastUsers
table: users
column1: email
column2: password
column3: firstName
column4: lastName
```

Right now in PHP non-Propel version, I'm doing all this by hand, and switching databases manually as required.  I'm hoping to streamline things a bit, and I'm curious how to model this.  Is there a way I can just have something like eastCoastUser and westCoastUser models that each refer to the proper database/etc or am I trying to wedge in something not supported?

I read this: [How to use two database in propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908956/how-to-use-two-database-in-propel) but am uncertain how to actually execute that in code.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you explain more about how you want to use this data?  Are you hoping to use `UserQuery` to search against both databases?  Or maybe, do you want website-users from the west coast to search against one database, and east coasters the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema files, you can provide a name for the class that represents your table.  They do not have to use the same name as the table.  You do this with the `phpName` attribute on the table element.

For example your schema.xml could contain something like this

```
<database name="westCoastUsers">
  <table name="users" phpName="WestCoastUser">
    ...columns here...
  </table>
  ...
</database>
<database name="eastCoastUsers">
  <table name="users" phpName="EastCoastUser">
    ...columns here...
  </table>
</database>
```

(edit, note that the `name="westCoastUser"` on the database element refers to the name of the database, not the classes with similar names)

Then at build time, propel will generate `WestCoastUser`, `WestCoastUserQuery`, `WestCoastUserPeer`, `EastCoastUser`, `EastCoastUserQuery` and, `EastCoastUserPeer`.  Each class will connect using the database it was defined under in your schema.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want/need.  I'm going to test stuff out and should post/reward by the end of the week.  Thanks for the quick response Joeshmo.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this originally for symfony 1.2, but I believe it all applies.

I’m using Symfony 1.2.4 for this example.I have two databases, master and slave

If you are going to use multiple databases, there are a few things that you are going to need to do.

```
You will need separate schema files for both (master.schema.yml and slave.schema.yml)
To use build-sql and insert-sql, you will need multiple propel.ini files
You will need to add an attribute to your schema files to get them to build right
```

Step 1

Create the databases.yml with two separate connections:

```
dev:
  propel:
  param:
  classname: DebugPDO

test:
  propel:
  param:
  classname: DebugPDO

all:
  propel:
  class: sfPropelDatabase
  param:
  classname: PropelPDO
  dsn: mysql:dbname=master;host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  username: uname
  password: pass
  encoding: utf8
  persistent: true
  pooling: true

master:
  class: sfPropelDatabase
  param:
  classname: PropelPDO
  dsn: mysql:dbname=slave;host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  username: uname
  password: pass
  encoding: utf8
  persistent: true
  pooling: true
```

Step 2

As mentioned you will need two schema files. Please notice that you will need to define a package attribute for the database that matches up to the tables, and in this case it is ‘lib.model.master’ for the master connection.

master.schema.yml

```
master:
  _attributes:
  package: lib.model.master
  defaultIdMethod: native
my_table:
  _attributes: { package: lib.model.master }
  my_id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
```

etc.....

slave.schema.yml

```
slave:
 _attributes:
 package: lib.model.slave
 defaultIdMethod: native
 auctionp:
 _attributes: { package: lib.model.slave }
```

etc.....

Step 3

You will need to create separate propel.ini files. In this example I used propel-master.ini and propel-slave.ini. Each of these files need to be configured for their respective databases.

Step 4

You will need a good batch file to build your your databases using the propel tools. Mine looks like this:

From the application root:
symfony build-model; cp config/slave-propel.ini config/propel.ini; symfony propel:build-sql; symfony propel:insert-sql --no-confirmation; cp config/propel-master.ini config/propel.ini; symfony propel:build-sql; symfony propel:insert-sql --no-confirmation;

Step 5

You will need to clean out /lib/model if you already built your model using one database and are now doing a split. Deleting the files in the “map” and “om” directories and the root directory will help you avoid conflicts.

Step 6

To use the two databases in code, you will need to add a bit to the connection, like the following:

Example 1:

```
$object = self::doSelect($c, Propel::getConnection('master'));
```

Example 2:

```
$newObject->save(Propel::getConnection('slave'));
```

Example 3:

```
$con = Propel::getConnection("propel");
$sql = "ALTER TABLE runlinhp CHANGE class class_rat varchar(15)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```