# Multi-tenant application with Propel ORM

Tags: php, multi-tenant, propel2

I am currently a developer of a multi-tenant application in which there is a "master" database, which holds customer's data and is also used as a template, that is, it gets copied with a different name for each new customer, to hold its data.

When using [Propel ORM](http://propelorm.org/) in PHP, the model configuration is done in an XML file structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="master_db" defaultIdMethod="native">
  <!-- here are tables' definitions -->
</database>
```

Is it possible to use the same XML file to model all the connections to all of the customers' databases, or would I need a separate file for each one, completely identical except for the database name?

As my question has been marked as a potential duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270008/propel-multiple-database-modeling), which I had found before, I'd like to explain why it is different:

- in this case, the number of databases **will change over time**, while in that question it is fixed
- in this case, all the databases and all the tables in each, will have **exactly** the same structure
- I do **not** want different classes for each customer, but rather a single set of model classes, which will query the last selected database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Propel Multiple Database Modeling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270008/propel-multiple-database-modeling)

Comment: @Dez I had seen that before, I do not think my question is really a dupe though.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for sounds a good candidate for XML Inclusions in the configuration files:

The `master-db.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="master_db" defaultIdMethod="native">
  <!-- here are tables' definitions -->
</database>
```

alongside the `propel.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <propel>
    <database name="blueberryshoechamp_db" defaultIdMethod="native">
      <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                  href="master-db.xml"
                  xpointer="xpointer( /database/* )"
                  />
    </database>
  ...
```

This will then include all child-elements of the `database` document element from the `master-db.xml` file.

Just the mixing you're looking for.

The good news: Propel2 supports this now, the feature was introduced in:

- [Support of XML Inclusions for the XML Configuration files #1321](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/1321)

Comment: If this gets implemented, it would really be what I am looking for! This also confirms that, as of now, I would need to copy the whole XML file too, right?

Comment: Yes, but you could externalize the process and generalte the propel.xml document with some PHP script.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: This has landed in Propel2 now, https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/commit/b311676a95eef3dacc229424e73be04992dd7b78